# display a window alert on click

Tags: javascript, apex-code, visualforce

I'm not sure how to do this, and can use some advice.

I created a custom button on a standard page layout, and when the user clicks it, I want to check if the user has contacts in this object.

If he doesn't, I want to display an alert- "please add contacts" and and return him to his current **STANDARD** page. Otherwise, I want him to get to a new VF page that is already written.
I'm not sure how to do this...

HALP!

Code:

```
<apex:page standardController="MY_List__c" extensions="MYListExtension" >
<apex:form >

           <script>
                var hasContact = {!totalContacts};
                if(hasContact == 0 ){
                    alert('Please add contacts!'); 
                    window.location ="/" + {"!theListId"};                    
                       }
                     else{
                          window.location = "/MYListSend?id=" + {"!theListId"};
                }

            </script>

            </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

The apex class:

```
public Boolean checkContact { get; set; }
public Boolean hasContact   { get; set; }

public PageReference myMethod(){
    // your logic here
    hasContact = true;
    checkContact = true;

    return null;
}
```

And the visualforce page:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Check user data" action="{!myMethod}" reRender="checkArea"/>

<apex:outputPanel id="checkArea">
    <apex:outputPanel id="showAfterCheck" rendered="{!checkContact}">
            <script>
                var hasContact = {!hasContact};
                if(!hasContact){
                    alert('Please add contacts!');
                    window.location = "/apex/YourCustomPageName1";
                }
                else{
                    window.location = "/apex/YourCustomPageName2";
                }

            </script>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: THIS IS FANTASTIC! i'm having a problem with the redirects though. I want the first case to go back to a standard SF detail page, not a VF page. IS there a way to do that? also the second redirect isn't working either... i'm doing this from a custom btn on a standard page layout.

Comment: Oh yeah: to redirect to the standard Salesforce page just do window.location = "/{!Id}";

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this in apex as it is server side language, in javascript however this is possible.

Comment: I've never done any java script, so i guess I get to learn now. Can you walk me through an outline for this?

Comment: First you need to get the element: var ele=document.getElementById('{!$Component.componentname}'); then you can do if statements and act accordingly whether the element is empty or not. You can google this part